# How to migrate images to new field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2.3, Mongoid, Attachinary and Cloudinary for images.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_attachment :image, accept: [:jpg, :png, :gif]

  field :pic, type: String

  before_update :migrate_images

  def migrate_images
    self.image_url = self.pic
  end
end
```

Images are saved in **pic** field as links.
Now I use this code, the problem is that this takes a very long time and not all images are saved.

```
User.where(:pic.exists => true).all.each &:update
```

log

```
irb(main):001:0> User.where(:pic.exists => true).all.each &:update
=> #<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:0x00007ffe5a3f98e0 @cache=nil, @klass=User, @criteria=#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"pic"=>{"$exists"=>true}}
  options:  {}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
, @collection=#<Mongo::Collection:0x70365213493680 namespace=link_development.users>, @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x70365213493380 namespace='link_development.users' @filter={"pic"=>{"$exists"=>true}} @options={"session"=>nil}>, @cache_loaded=true>
```

Comment: What is `:pic.exists`? Symbol doesn't have an `exists` method.

Comment: @Schwern to determine if there are images

Comment: @Schwern With this code, I cut off users who do not have images

Comment: Can you try running the update by first retrieving a list of all the users and then looping over and checking how long each one takes? Is there anything in common for the ones that take a time or the ones that don't save?

Comment: @AntonIpatov Does `User.where(:pic.exists => true).all.each &:update` execute on your system? It has multiple errors. `:pic.exists` gives `NoMethodError: undefined method `exists' for :pic:Symbol` and `update` takes an argument, `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, but if the number of images is more than 20000, not all images are transferred.  I updated the code and added a log

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov I'll try to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.where(:pic.exists => true).all.each &:update
```

This is slow because `.all.each` loads all matching Users into memory, [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) is a bit more efficient on memory as it will load in batches, but it's still a waste of time and memory to load each object into memory and turn it into an object to copy one attribute. Then it runs an `update` on each individual one.

Instead, you can do this entirely in the database in a single query.

---

If the intent is to copy from `User.pic` to `User.image_url`, you can do this in a single statement.

```
# Find all the users who do not already have an image_url set
User.where(image_url: nil)
    # Set their image_url to be their pic.
    .update_all("image_url = pic")
```

This will run a single query:

```
update users
  set image_url = pic
  where image_url is null
```

There's no need to also check for users who lack a `pic` because there's no harm in setting nil to nil, and a simpler search might be faster. But if you like check you can use [`where.not`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not). `Users.where(image_url: nil).where.not(pic: nil)`